# Saving R output in Google Colab

Tags: r, google-colaboratory

How do I save R output into a file in google colab? It could be saved on google drive or my local drive, either would work.

For example, if I wanted to save a list of R objects in a RDS file, normally I would have used something like this on RStudio.

`saveRDS(list(a, b, c, d), file = "C:\\sim1.rds")`

I am looking to do something similar on Google colab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recently I found the answer so I wanted to write it here in case it is useful for others.

To save an output on my google drive we need to mount it using the following.

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
```

Then we can navigate to MyDrive using the following.

```
cd /content/drive/MyDrive
```

Now that we are in MyDrive, we can run the code and save outputs on MyDrive. Then we can download it to our laptop.